# How to replace multiple character from single one?

Tags: php

My variable contains string like `"1,5,4,,,,6,4,9,12,55,,,4,,,,9,,,,,"` and I want to get output like `"1,5,4,6,4,9,12,55,4,9"`. I know there are many ways to do this in C#. but, Now I am doing code in php. So, I could not use any .net feature.

There is a loop which is processing on all lines to remove unnecessary comma and the length of list might be more than 15000.

I don't have enough knowledge about php. I am a self learner.

Comment: So you are trying to `replace` some `string` heh

Comment: You could use a simple regular expression with `preg_replace` for example …

Comment: @PeeHaa the record will be retrieved from CSV file. But, it is not a table formatted. I want to show all value in one row without skipping any blank cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explode it, remove the empty value, and implode it again.

```
$str = "1,5,4,,,,6,4,9,12,55,,,4,,,,9,,,,,"; 
$str = implode(',', array_filter(explode(',', $str)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Using regular expression.

```
$v = "a,b,,,,,,c,d,f,,,,t";
 $x = preg_replace("/,{2,}/", ",", $v);
 echo $x;
```

And the result:

```
a,b,c,d,f,t
```

Note:

PHP Regular Expression is highly optimized and would probably takes less time (hence resources) to finish the process (than takes array explode..)

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` should work -

```
$pattern = Array('/,{2,}/','/,{1,}$/');
$replace = Array(",","");
$string = "1,5,4,,,,6,4,9,12,55,,,4,,,,9,,,,,";
$res = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
var_dump($res);
/** OUTPUT **/
//string '1,5,4,6,4,9,12,55,4,9' (length=22)
```